# HTTP/2 and SPDY running together in Apache

Tags: web-server, performance, apache-2.4, https, spdy

I have the latest Apache installed and currently support HTTP/2. Can I setup SPDY and run it together with HTTP/2?

The goal is to also take advantage of the SPDY for browsers that do not support HTTP/2.

Thanks.

Comment: You would probably need to be more specific in what you want to support as SPDY ended up having multiple versions, with at least some level of incompatibility between them. Apache never supported SPDY 3.1 I believe, which was just different enough from 3.0 to break things. Is your concern older Android devices that don't, and never will, support HTTP2  but may have some level of SPDY support? There was a discussion on the NGinx blog which suggested that it might not be worth the trouble : https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-open-source-reflecting-back-and-looking-ahead/#comment-2279271562

Comment: @JeremyGibbons Thanks for the helpful insights. Apparently you can install mod_spdy in Apache but you need to consider compatibility - https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/#install-module